# TrustZone GCC example (Cortex A9 - ZedBoard Zynq 7000)

Tags: gcc, arm, zynq, trustzone

I am trying to run a simple TrustZone example on the ZedBoard, just a bare metal program that switches between Secure World and Normal World. Are any such examples available for the GCC compiler? The official ARM example is written mostly in ARM Assembly. I have already started porting the example over to GCC, but I am experiencing quite a lot of problems with that, as I am not very experienced in either of the Assembly dialects